# Как вызвать функцию, если не completed? (mask())

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, mask

```
$('.info-panel input').mask('+38(099)999-99-99', {
        completed: function () {
            $('.info-panel button').removeAttr("disabled");

        }
    });
```

Собственно, когда пользователь ввел телефон, кнопка разблокируется, но стоит ему удалить цифру и ничего не происходит.

Как сделать блокировку, если **не `completed`**?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать проверку после изменения, как пример(надо протестировать)

```
$('.info-panel input').mask('+38(099)999-99-99', {
        completed: function () {
            $('.info-panel button').removeAttr("disabled");
        },
      onChange: function(){
          if (this.value.trim().length < 17) {
        console.log('Некорректное значение');
        $('.info-panel button').attr("disabled");

      }
        },
    });
```

Comment: onChange: не срабатывает, как и onKeyPress

Comment: @EduardRST вы используете плагин `jQuery-Mask-Plugin` ? если да, то метод `onChange` должен работать, ещё раз проверьте.

Comment: похоже я использую что-то другое. Обошел простой дополнительной функцией